# Synchronize multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to make a multithreaded application (up to lets say 100 thread) in Delphi XE5, 
all the thread are going to use/change a listbox in the main form, 
here is my code: 
Main Unit:

```
private
  //list to hold the dynamic created threads
  SendThreads : TObjectList;
public
  mutex : boolean;
...
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ...
   mutex := false;
   SendThreads := TObjectList.Create;
end;

...

//Button to create and start the threads
procedure TMainForm.btnWorkClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread : TSendThread;
  i, nbr : integer;
begin
  if SendThreads.Count < spnThreadCount.Value then
  begin
    for I := 1 to spnThreadCount.Value - SendThreads.Count do
    begin

      nbr := SendThreads.Add(TSendThread.Create(true));

      Thread := TSendThread(SendThreads.Items[nbr]);

      Thread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
      Thread.Start;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Thread Unit:

```
    uses MainUnit;

    procedure TSendThread.Execute;
    begin
      QueryList;
    end;

//Basically, this procedure checks if the item in the listbox contains '- Done.' which means that this
//item has been done by another thread, if not, the current thread deal with this item.
procedure TSendThread.QueryList;
var i : integer;
    S : String;
begin
  i := 0;
  while i < MainForm.lstURL.Count do
  begin

    while MainForm.mutex do;

    MainForm.mutex := true;

    if pos(' - Done.', MainForm.lstURL.Items[i]) = 0 then
    begin
      S := MainForm.lstURL.Items[i];
      Delete(S, 1, pos('?txt=', S) + length('?txt=') - 1);
      MainForm.Memo1.Lines.Add(MainForm.lstURL.Items[i]);
      MainForm.lstURL.Items[i] := MainForm.lstURL.Items[i] + ' - Done.';

      MainForm.mutex := false;
      SendAd(URL, S);
    end
    else
    begin
      Inc(i);
      MainForm.mutex := false;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This method works if the number of the threads are less than 4, but if it's more i get redundant result (2 or more threads do the same item).
Now i'm fairly new to threads and multithreading, and i was wondering if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: For probably the one-thousandth time (and as directly stated in both the Delphi documentation and the huge auto-generated comment block when you use File->New->Other->Thread Object in the IDE): You **cannot** access VCL controls directly from your thread without using `Synchronize` or `Queue`. (Use the menu item I mention, and **read that large comment block carefully**.)

Comment: Yes i read that and i actualy used that function in another project but in this project i want to use up to 100 threads at the same time, if there is a way to use the "synchronize" method with that much of threads please tell me.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you want to use 100 threads. You **cannot** access VCL controls from a thread without using Synchronize, whether you want to do so or not. It's not a matter of whether or not it suits your needs - you **cannot** do it. There's a reason the documentation, generated code comments, and many previous answers here say the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Ken said about UI safety, you are getting threads processing the same item because you have a race condition on your `mutex` variable. Multiple threads may see `mutex=false` at the same time as they are not actually syncing with each otber. You need to use a true mutex. Look at the `TMutex` class. Or just wrap the majority of your code in `TThread.Synchronize()` and let the VCL handle the syncing for you. But then that defeats the purpose of using threads.

You are using the **completely** wrong design for your requirement.  You need to separate your worker thread logic from your UI logic.  There are a few different ways you can do that.

1. Put your work jobs into a thread-safe queue, like `TThreadList<T>` or `TThreadedQueue<T>`. Each thread can check the queue periodically and pull the next available job if there is one.

   A. A variation is to use an I/O Completion Port as the queue. Post jobs to the IOCP using `PostQueuedCompletionStatus()`, and have each thread use `GetQueuedCompletionResult()` to receive jobs.  This allows the OS to do all the queuing and pulling for you, while allowing threads to sleep when there are no jobs available.
2. Put your threads into a pool in a sleeping state.  When a new job is ready, check the pool.  If a thread is available, pull it from the pool, pass the job to it, and wake it up.  Otherwise put the job in a thread-safe queue. When a job is done, have that thread check the queue. If a job is available, pull it from the queue, otherwise put the thread in the poll and put it back to sleep.

In any case, when a job is done being processed, that thread can notify the main thread of the job result, using `TThread.Synchronize()`, `TThread.Queue()`, or any other inter-thread communication of your choosing.  The main thread can then update the UI as needed.

At no point should the threads touch the UI to discover new jobs.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what you wrote very well, i didn't understand how to "put my `jobs` in a thread-safe queue" and how to "put threads into a pool in a sleeping state". Can you please explain more?

Comment: Define a `record` or `class` that contains all of the information needed for a single job, then create an instance of that when needed and put it into a `TThreadList` or `TThreadedQueue` object for your threads to pull from.  Create a list of `TSendThread` objects, and give each thread a `TEvent` that is signaled only when the thread has a job to do and then reset when finished. The thread can then sleep by waiting on that event.

Comment: The list of `TSendThread`is also a `TThreadList` or `TThreadedQueue`?

Comment: It can be whatever you want as long as you access it in a safe manner. It depends on how you put threads back into the list, whether idle threads put themselves into the list directly or signal the main thread to do it. The former requires syncing, the latter does not.